MassTransit StateMachine/State shows message received, but does not move to process
I am using a StateMachine, I find occasional messages appear to become stalled and will not move forward. For example, a small set had five of six complete as expected.
I reviewed the tracing logs and it seems the message gets to the 'receive' portion of the message handling in the MassTransit flow. When the message works as expected it then moves to 'process'. I have not been able to determine what would obstruct this message from moving to the next stage.

I would suggest you either create a standalone repository reproducing the problem and post on the MassTransit GitHub Discussions, or contact support if you have a support agreement.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
